# docker compose initial creation of database makes service fail to start

Tags: docker-compose

I have a problem.
I have a database to a REST service called `app_user_api` below.
When I initially start I have no data at all, so the database becomes populated first by mysql in the folder `db_data/mysql` as noted below in the yml, and secondarily by the REST API itself.

The initial time I start up my service fails to start since the creation of the database is under progress. When I wait out the database worker to just finish then do `docker compose down` followed by `docker compose up` it all works and the REST API database becomes populated and the service starts as expected.

I thought my condition was correctly described as:

```yaml
    depends_on:
      mysql_test_db:
        condition: service_started
```

Or have I missed something else?

Ideally I would like to wipe my local folder db_data and then restart everything on the first attempt, instead of having to ad-hoc wait and then restart the services again.

This is my docker-compose

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  mysql_test_db:
    image: mysql
    container_name: mysql_test_db
    command: --init-file /data/application/init.sql
    volumes:
      - ./init.sql:/data/application/init.sql
      - ./db_data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/mysql_db_password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: TEST_SS_REST_API_1
    ports:
      - "3306"
    networks:
      - net_db
    secrets:
      - mysql_db_password
    restart: unless-stopped

  app_user_api:
    depends_on:
      mysql_test_db:
        condition: service_started
    image: fast-api-beta
    container_name: test_user_api_1
    volumes:
      - /etc/certificates/site:/certs:ro
    environment:
      APP_KEY_MYSQL_USERNAME: root
      APP_KEY_MYSQL_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/mysql_db_password
      APP_KEY_MYSQL_DATABASE: TEST_SS_REST_API_1
      APP_KEY_MYSQL_DOMAIN: mysql_test_db
      APP_KEY_MYSQL_PORT: 3306
    ports:
      - "18000:8080"
    expose:
      - "18000"
    networks:
      - net_db
      - net_api
    secrets:
      - mysql_db_password

networks:
  net_db:
  net_api:

secrets:
  mysql_db_password:
    file: ./mysql_db_password.txt
```

This is the file init.sql

```sql
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS TEST_SS_REST_API_1
```

The file `mysql_db_password.txt` contains a cleartext password.

Thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I missed one minor detail...

I forgot this under my service:

```
  app_user_api:
    # rest as described originally
    restart: unless-stopped
```

Now it seems to try to restart until it succeeds.